# details of CreateSqlQuery( )

Tags: sql, hql

I am new to **Hibernate** and I need help/answers for few doubts.

1) I am using Oracle 10g dialect and If I use Session.CreateSqlQuery("Oracle syntax SQL Query");

My Question: If I change my dialect to **SQL Server 2008**. will the query which I have created by using CreateSqlQuery() changes/run's on **SQL server 2008**.?
or Do i need to change the Query once again.

Thanks & Regards, 
Anand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the dialect  of  SQL server 2008.
It is database dependent.You cannot use same dialect for both databases

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response.

say I changed the dialect to SQL Server 2008 or any other database dialect.

my question is, will the same sql query which is created by using CreateSqlQuery() is sufficient for all DB dialects or do I need to change the sql query every time when I change the Dialect.

Comment: you need to change to SqlServer 2008 dialect

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response. say I changed the dialect to SQL Server 2008 or any other database dialect. my question is, will the same sql query which is created by using CreateSqlQuery() is sufficient for all DB dialects or do I need to change the sql query every time when I change the Dialect